# Segmentation fault(signal 11)

Tags: c, linux, mpi

I'm new to coding and started learning MPI through examples. After executing with mpirun -np 7 ./lab1part2 , I encountered this problem.

I read a few other threads with similar error but non of them seems to be an identical case to me. I'm guessing that I made some simple error syntax wise but i just can't find it. Thanks in advance for any helpful input!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int Global_sum(int my_int, int my_rank, int comm_sz, MPI_Comm comm); 
const int MAX_CONTRIB = 20;

int main(void) {
   int i, sum, my_int;
   int my_rank, comm_sz;
   MPI_Comm comm;
   int* all_ints = NULL;

   MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
   comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
   MPI_Comm_size(comm, &comm_sz);
   MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &my_rank);

   srandom(my_rank + 1);
   my_int = random() % MAX_CONTRIB;

   sum = Global_sum(my_int, my_rank, comm_sz, comm);

   if ( my_rank == 0) {
      all_ints = malloc(comm_sz*sizeof(int));
      MPI_Reduce(&my_int, &all_ints, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);
      printf("Ints being summed:\n   ");
      for (i = 0; i < comm_sz; i++)
         printf("%d ", all_ints[i]);
      printf("\n");
      printf("Sum = %d\n",sum);
      free(all_ints);
   } else {
      MPI_Reduce(&my_int, &all_ints, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);
   }

   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}  

int Global_sum(
      int my_int,
      int my_rank,
      int comm_sz,
      MPI_Comm comm ) {

   int partner, recvtemp;
   int my_sum = my_int;
   unsigned bitmask = 1;

   while (bitmask < comm_sz) {
      partner = my_rank ^ bitmask;

      if (my_rank < partner) {
         if (partner < comm_sz) {
            MPI_Recv(&recvtemp, 1, MPI_INT, partner, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            my_sum += recvtemp;
         }
         bitmask <<= 1;
      } else {
         MPI_Send(&my_sum, 1, MPI_INT, partner, 0, comm);  
         break;
      }
   } 

   return my_sum;
}
```

Comment: your code suggests you really need to `MPI_Gather(&my_int, all_ints, ...)` (Note there is no `&` for the receive buffer argument).

Comment: Thanks for the help! The code works as intended now.